# How to sort/order a post modul with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to sort/order all "events" from a custom field, named "dato_for_arrangementet"

I have added this code to functions.php in my child theme and the code works fine in the post archive, but NOT in the post module on a page, where i need it.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    
    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        
        return $query;
        
    }
    

    // only modify queries for 'event' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'event' )  {
        
        
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');    
        $query->set('meta_key', 'dato_for_arrangementet');     
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
        
    }
    

    // return
    return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: What is a "post module"?

Comment: I am using the Uncode Theme with WPBackery PageBuilder. The "post module" is a block you can add on any page and will get posts from a specific post type or category. You have the choice to sort/order post from "published date", "ID", "Title", "radom" etc.. But i need to sort/order by meta_value (ACFfield) Datepicker.

Comment: Maybe that somehow queries the data to show using different query_vars than the ones you are checking for there - so I'd start by logging those. The filter callback will likely execute multiple times on any given page, so you will have to try and figure out which combination belongs to the relevant query then. The Query Monitor plugin could perhaps also help shed some light on the issue.